# Parse File.save() odd behaviour

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm uploading a picture to parse.com using the following two ways. The first one using promises works, but the other doesn't. Am I missing something very basic?

Method 1:

```
var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
parseFile.save().then(function (){
   console.log('Picture has been successfully saved.');
   callback(pictype, parseFile);
}, function (error){
   console.log('Picture cannot be saved.', error.toString());
});
```

Method 2:

```
var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
parseFile.save(null, {
  success: function () {
    console.log('Picture has been successfully saved.');
    callback(pictype, parseFile);
  },
  error: function (error) {
    console.log('Picture cannot be saved.', error.toString());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the save method on Parse.File is implemented. It clearly returns a promise since that code works...it probably does not support the success and error syntax. Your code will not fail on it however it just doesn't work.

Edit: looking at the documentation you need to specify the options object (containing the success and error methods) as first argument. That is where you now specify null.

Comment: You are right that the code doesn't fail, but it doesn't work. To me, it seems like a bug as the documentation suggests that both should just work fine - https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html.

Comment: Yes, i looks like it. But you are speciying null as first argument instead of the options object...

Comment: It is same situation in parse version 1.11.1. The first argument is null will stuck Parse.File class saving while it is ok for normal object saving